# Cannot extract variable with RegEx from a Mail Reader in jMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following setup:

- Thread

  - Mail Reader Sampler

    - Regular Expression Extractor
    - Viewer
  - HTTP Sampler
  - Viewer

What I'm trying to do is retrieve an email, extract a value from it and then pass it as a variable in the next request.

The problem is that the retrieved email comes in the following format:

- Mail Reader Sampler

  - Message 1

    - Part 0
    - Part 1

The info that I'm aiming for is located in "Part 1". And this is causing my problem...jMeter can not extract it because it is a sub-sub-sample.
If the desired variable was located in the "Message 1" part, then jMeter is extracting the value without any problems and is then passing it to the next request.

My RegEx setting is "Apply to main sample and sub-samples", so theoretically, this shouldn't be a problem..but apparently is.

How can I get jMeter to extract the wanted value when the retrieved email comes in multiple sub-parts?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Regular Expression Extractor processes only direct sub-samples so in case of multipart email messages you will be able to extract only `This is a multipart message in MIME format.` line which is not very helpful.

I would recommend adding a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the Mail Reader Sampler but **before** the Regular Expression Extractor and use the following code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

for (SampleResult message : prev.getSubResults()) {
    response.append(message.getResponseDataAsString());
    for (SampleResult part : message.getSubResults()) {
         response.append(part.getResponseDataAsString());
    }
}

prev.setResponseData(response.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

The above code will traverse down all the messages and their parts, extract response data and substitute Mail Reader Sampler's default response data `X messages found` with the actual contents of these message(s) so you will be able to use the Regular Expression Extractor for correlation.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for comprehensive information on using scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to solve my problem in the manner you've described